# To get the sum of values from Xml innertags of unique type, through XmlDocument

Tags: .net, xml, loops, foreach, nodes

Through XmlDocument, I want to get the sum of all the quantities with Partnumber '500300-B21'. My code in C# is :-

```
XmlDocument xworkload = new XmlDocument();
private void BtnPnoCount_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".hpa"; // Default file extension
    dlg.Filter = "Xml documents (.hpa)|*.hpa"; // Filter files by extension 

    var result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    if (result == true)
    {
        xworkload.Load(dlg.FileName);
        string xmlcontents = xworkload.InnerXml; // To get inner Xml

     if (null != xworkload.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Interview"))
        {
            if (xworkload.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Interview/Rack")!= null)
            {
                var xpath = "//Item/partnumber";

                XmlNodeList qtysum = xworkload.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(xpath);
                int sum = 0;

                foreach (XmlNode node in qtysum)
                {
                    if (node.SelectSingleNode("partnumber").InnerText == "500300-B21")
                    {
                        sum += Int32.Parse(node.SelectSingleNode("quantity").InnerText);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("The the sum of quantities with P/No 500300-B21 is " + sum.ToString());
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This throws NullReferenceException. I want to get the sum of quantities with that partnumber

Comment: FYI, XmlDocument is part of .NET, not part of C#

Comment: @JohnSaunders : Thanks, I have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Load Doc
    var xworkload = new XmlDocument();
    xworkload.Load("C:\\temp\\xmldoc.xml");

    var sum = 0;
    // Loop through each processor/item node
    foreach (XmlNode node in xworkload.SelectNodes("//Processor/Item"))
    {
         // Check part number
         if (node.SelectSingleNode("partnumber").InnerText == "500300-B21")
         {
             // Add to sum
             sum += Int32.Parse(node.SelectSingleNode("quantity").InnerText);
         }
    }  
}
```

Comment: @ Dannyh, Thanks, It worked for the partnumbers under Processor.

Comment: Yep, your original post had processor in it, for all items just change
`XmlNode node in xworkload.SelectNodes("//Processor/Item")`
to
`XmlNode node in xworkload.SelectNodes("//Item")`

Answer (score 1):

Using `LINQ to XML` it's easier, try this one:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(dlg.FileName);
var sum = xDoc.Descendants("item")
              .Where(item => (string)item.Element("partnumber") == "500300-B21")
              .Select(x => (int)x.Element("quantity"))
              .Sum();
```

Or more safe version:

```
var sum = xDoc.Descendants("item")
              .Where(item => (string)item.Element("partnumber") == "500300-B21")
              .Select(x =>
              {
                  int result;
                  if (int.TryParse((string) x.Element("quantity"), out result)) 
                     return result;
                  else 
                     return 0;
              })
              .Sum();
```

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Can you suggest something taking this XmlDocument into reference, I cannot use LINQ to Xml.

Comment: @MishraSaurabh I don't use `XmlDocument`. Why can't you use LINQ to XML?

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in a single XPath query

For sum of all processor quantities:

```
sum(//Processor/Item[partnumber='500300-B21']/quantity)
```

For all Items quantities:

```
sum(//Item[partnumber='500300-B21']/quantity)
```

Note that according to your xml, `partnumber` is an element, not an attribute, so omit the `@`.
Your doc also isn't well formed (`<?xml ...`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer, It worked.

```
if (null != xworkload.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Interview"))
                    {
                        if (xworkload.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Interview/Rack")!= null)
                        {
                            var xpath = "//Item";

                            XmlNodeList qtysum = xworkload.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(xpath);
                            int sum = 0;

                            foreach (XmlNode node in qtysum)
                            {
                                if (node.SelectSingleNode("partnumber").InnerText == "500300-B21")
                               {
                                   sum += Int32.Parse(node.SelectSingleNode("quantity").InnerText);
                               }                           
                            }

                            MessageBox.Show("The the sum of quantities with P/No 500300-B21 is " + sum.ToString());

    }

}
```